# Orientation of segments of a polygon in ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, python

Using the longest side of a polygon, I would like to get the orientation of each side of the polygon with the longest side orientation as the reference.

I have attempted to get the general orientation of each segment of a polygon using:

```py
def minBG(inFC, outFC):
     arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management(inFC, outFC, geometry_type="RECTANGLE_BY_AREA", group_option="NONE", mbg_fields_option=True)
```

The result gives *MBG_Length* and *MBG_Orient* in the attribute table of each polygon but unable to proceed from here.

Comment: OGC standard is exterior rings are clockwise, holes are counter clockwise. http://esri.github.io/geometry-api-java/doc/Polygon.html, provided your data is simple (containing no errors with self intersecting polygons) you can rely on that.

Comment: Hi @MichaelStimson , Thank you for that. Yes, the polygons are simple and valid. I am not sure how to proceed with getting by how much the line segments change orientation. For example, in a polygon, I have their individual segment orientation and length but I need to get more like the inner angles at each vertex with the longest side orientation as reference.

Comment: You will need to iterate the vertices, have a look at https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001t000000 from there it should be a fairly simple math, an example https://help.trimblegeospatial.com/TrimbleAccess/2018.00/en/Pipelines/ComputeDeflectionAngle.htm?TocPath=Apps%7CPipelines%7CPipeline%20Cogo%20functions%7C_____3 . You will need to iterate to n-1 as polygons have the same point for start and end, two variables: from point and forward length, updated if the length is longer (Pythagoras at work here https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html).

Comment: Thank you for the tips @MichaelStimson . Looks like what I should be doing and will try it out. Should in case you can help with providing a "direct" solution (python scripting), that would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried "Split line at vertices" tool?

Comment: Thank you for the tip @BERA . Could you walk me through what the ideal workflow starting with your suggestion?

Comment: What is your desired output? A table with each polygon id and its orientation in degrees?

Comment: Yes, that is the needed output @BERA . Thank you!